# Changing ProdRouteJob has no effect to WrkCtrCapRes or recalculating the capacity reservations

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++, ax

I'm changing the route jobs (ProdRouteJob) with optimised data from an external optimisation tool. The changed data is written with a simple ax class and a prodRouteJob.update().
The problem now is, that the capacity reservations (WrkCtrCapRes) will not get updated. Is the a way to recalculate the capacity reservations? Or create new capacity reservations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only place where `WrkCtrCapRes` is updated is in the `WrkCtrJobData.updateCapacityReservations()` method. The class `WrkCtrJobData` requires `WrkCtrScheduleJobs` and other deep down complexities.

The `ProdRouteJob` does not have the full knowledge to update capacity reservation, it will have to take calendar into consideration.

I have made the following method to do a similar update. It does not support "Base calendar", but otherwise did what I needed.

```
Hours updateWrkCtrCapRes(ProdRouteJob prodRouteJob, WrkCtrTable wrkCtrTable = WrkCtrTable::find(prodRouteJob.WrkCtrId))
{
    WrkCtrCapRes         wrkCtrCapRes;
    WorkCalendarDateLine workCalendarDateLine;
    Seconds              sec;    
    delete_from wrkCtrCapRes
        where wrkCtrCapRes.RefType     == WrkCtrCapRefType::Production &&
              wrkCtrCapRes.RefId       == prodRouteJob.ProdId &&
              wrkCtrCapRes.OprNum      == prodRouteJob.OprNum &&
              wrkCtrCapRes.OprPriority == prodRouteJob.OprPriority &&
              wrkCtrCapRes.JobId       == prodRouteJob.JobId;    
    wrkCtrCapRes.ReqPlanId     = ReqPlanSched::defaultDynamicId();
    wrkCtrCapRes.LoadType      = WrkCtrCapacityType::JobSched;
    wrkCtrCapRes.RefType       = WrkCtrCapRefType::Production;
    wrkCtrCapRes.RefId         = prodRouteJob.ProdId;
    wrkCtrCapRes.OprNum        = prodRouteJob.OprNum;
    wrkCtrCapRes.OprPriority   = prodRouteJob.OprPriority;
    wrkCtrCapRes.JobType       = prodRouteJob.JobType;
    wrkCtrCapRes.JobId         = prodRouteJob.JobId;
    wrkCtrCapRes.Locked        = prodRouteJob.Locked;    
    wrkCtrCapRes.WrkCtrGroupId = wrkCtrTable.WrkCtrGroupId;
    wrkCtrCapRes.WrkCtrId      = wrkCtrTable.WrkCtrId;
    wrkCtrCapRes.WrkCtrLoadPct = 100.0;    
    while select workCalendarDateLine
        where workCalendarDateLine.CalendarId == wrkCtrTable.CalendarId &&
              workCalendarDateLine.TransDate  >= prodRouteJob.FromDate &&
              workCalendarDateLine.TransDate  <= prodRouteJob.ToDate
    {
        if (workCalendarDateLine.TransDate == prodRouteJob.FromDate)
            workCalendarDateLine.FromTime   = max(workCalendarDateLine.FromTime, prodRouteJob.FromTime);
        if (workCalendarDateLine.TransDate == prodRouteJob.ToDate)
            workCalendarDateLine.ToTime     = min(workCalendarDateLine.ToTime, prodRouteJob.ToTime);
        if (workCalendarDateLine.FromTime < workCalendarDateLine.ToTime)
        {
            wrkCtrCapRes.TransDate = workCalendarDateLine.TransDate;
            wrkCtrCapRes.StartTime = workCalendarDateLine.FromTime;
            wrkCtrCapRes.EndTime   = workCalendarDateLine.ToTime;
            wrkCtrCapRes.WrkCtrSec = wrkCtrCapRes.EndTime - wrkCtrCapRes.StartTime;
            wrkCtrCapRes.insert();
            sec += wrkCtrCapRes.WrkCtrSec;
        }
    }
    return decRound(sec / 3600.0, 5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply added this method :

```
static void ProdSchedule(ProdId _ProdId) 
{
 ProdTableType ProdTableType;
 ProdTable ProdTable=ProdTable::find(_ProdId);
 ProdParmScheduling ProdParmScheduling;
 ; 
 ProdTableType=new ProdTableType(ProdTable);
 ProdParmScheduling = ProdParmScheduling::findLast(_ProdId,ProdSchedMethod::JobScheduling);     ProdTableType.runJobScheduling(ProdParmScheduling); 
}
```